# maven parent pom dependencies Inherit version but does not Inherit the exclusions

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have parent pom which contains all the projects versions and exclusions 
I would like to have the same exclusions from the parent in the child , how can I achieve it.

son-project project inherit his father version 
but takes artifact a, where i would like him to avoid taking a 
how can i do it?

my goal is that to have letters jar without a dependency

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  <groupId>parent</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somthing.ltetters</groupId>
        <artifactId>ltetters</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.somthing.ltetters</groupId>
                <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>son-project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>3.9.0.SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>parent-pom</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somthing.ltetters</groupId>
        <artifactId>ltetters</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already specified dependency in the parent pom, it will be inherited by all child artifacts and you don't need to specify it again. If you actually don't want to inherit it by default, then instead use the <[dependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)> in your parent pom and then specify dependency in the child project without version or excludes. So, your parent pom will look like this:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
  <groupId>parent</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.somthing.ltetters</groupId>
        <artifactId>ltetters</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.somthing.ltetters</groupId>
                <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    ...
  <dependencyManagement>
  ...
```

All child projects can still look the same as in your question.

Comment: I didnt understand, doing it manually in the child where I have 10 children whom I need to exclude is the situation I wish to avoid

Comment: mmmm , it does not work , i can see it in the child :  mvn dependency:tree

Comment: I've tried it on a toy project. Make sure you've installed your updated parent project into local Maven repository.

Comment: I have deleted the .2 repository on my local machine ...
again the behavior i am looking for is declaring on exclusion on the father pom in    <dependencyManagement> and the derived pom son, wont get this excluded jar transitively , while it does happen .

Comment: i used another verssion in the child so he didnot take his father

Comment: Was this resolved? Can you confirm that this worked?